# Cannot install python by requirements.txt

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pip, anaconda3

I try to install the python package using the following command line in anacondaprompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\Lenovo>pip install -r D:\autoencoder\Website_by_python\requirements.txt
```

Then the error is shown as

```
Processing c:\tmp\build\80754af9\backports.functools_lru_cache_1618170165463\work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\tmp\\build\\80754af9\\backports.functools_lru_cache_1618170165463\\work'
```

I don't really know how to deal with that error. Could you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not install packages due to an OSError
```

is always related to administrator privileges or even worse the python version that visual studio installs by default i suggest you to
uninstall python
delete the python extension from vs code
delete the python version in the data folder you can access it by run `%temp%`  and in the address bar click on app data from there look for python
finally reinstall python i suggest you directly to C: without any version numbers i.e c:/Python dont forget to click add variables to path then open visual studio again and let him install the python extension again

omg i just noticed you talk about anaconda nevertheless it should be exactly the same problem

Comment: I don't understand clearly. Do you mean I have to uninstall python in anaconda and reinstall it again?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).